# Grails blob to pdf

Tags: grails, groovy

I have stored a pdf file as a blob, an when I try to render it as a pdf in the browser, It looks like this:

```
%PDF-1.4 %���� 5 0 obj <>stream x��[]s�6}
```

This is my action in the controller I am using
   def showDetails = {

```
    def product = Sample.get(params.id)

    response.contentType = 'application/pdf' 
    response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=file.pdf')
    response.getOutputStream().write(product.file)

    response.getOutputStream().flush()

}
```

I also tried adding `response.characterEncoding = "utf 8"` and that didn't work either.

Just to clarify: I have a form that stores a pdf file as a blob. Once the object is stored in the database , the object and a few parameters (name, date, etc.) appears in my app. The name is clickable which will render a link to the blob file in a div:

```
<g:remoteLink id="${s.id}" update="details"  controller="submitSample"action="showDetails" >${s.sampleNameID}</g:remoteLink></td>
```

If I change getOutputStream to getBytes() like this, I get this error:

```
No signature of method: [B.getBytes() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Possible solutions: getClass(), getAt(groovy.lang.ObjectRange), getAt(java.lang.Integer), getAt(groovy.lang.IntRange), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(groovy.lang.Range).

Simply using product.file gives me garbled output.

Comment: What is product.file, is it a java.io.File or a Blob?  If it's a blob you'll need to convert it to a byte array first.

Answer (score 2):

Try also specifying the `Content-Disposition`:

```
response.contentType = 'application/pdf'
response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'Attachment; filename=file.pdf')
response.getOutputStream().write(product.file)
```

Comment: I am still getting the weird character string even after adding setHeader. I have updated my original post with the new suggestions.

Comment: @tim_yates I don't have a product domain class. product is a variable referring to the blob object.

Comment: I was not able to figure this out. Grails seems on its face to be simple, but it is most likely a tiny thing I did not do right that is making it not work. Instead, I solved my issue by uploading the file and transferring it to a folder inside the app, then store a link to the file inside the db. This way, I don't have to worry about rendering the blob, because the browser takes care of that. Once again, I had a few issues, because one would think things would work just as the 'Grails In Action' example shows, but alas, I did not get by that easy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what data type the `product.file` is but, assuming it is a `java.io.File` this could should work...

```
  response.setContentType('application/pdf');
  response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'Attachment; filename=file.pdf');
  response.getOutputStream().write(product.file.toNewInputStream());
  response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

**However**, if `product.file` is a blob you'll need to get the bytes out of it before you send it to the browser response...

```
 response.setContentType('application/pdf');
 response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'Attachment; filename=file.pdf');
 response.getOutputStream().write(product.file.getBytes());
 response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

**This is un-tested code but I think you get the idea**.  I think your seeing the weird chars printing to the browser output because it's just doing a toString() of you blob.  Enjoy.

Comment: File is a blob. I stored the blob in my db, and now i am trying to get it out and render it to the screen.

Comment: Also, I am not sure how to make the link: `<img  src="${createLink(controller:'file', action:'showImage', id:WHAT GOES HERE??? )}" />`

Comment: The id is the HTML element id but is commonly used to store domain class database identifiers in grails.  This is a fundamental concept and I suggest you run through some tutorials before getting lost or post another question.

Comment: I have taken a course in Grails and I have 'grails in Action'. It is easy to get lost in the syntax of grails because in this case, id is different as you say, and I am unclear on that. I understand what you are implying, however, your comment does nothing to help me. A link or explanation would be better to help me understand.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean for my comment to sound like it did.  I ment; I suggest you ask a new question about the use of id in grails elements because it's a different topic. :)

Comment: No problem Michael. I definitely appreciate the help.